# how to kill log running jobs in every one hour interval?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to search all the jobs which are running more that one hour. kill them. Then sleep for 60 mins. Again search if any job is running more than 60? loop the process.

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far and take a look at how to ask good questions: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the PIDs for the processes running for more than 60 minutes on your linux box you can use a very simple and basic bash script like the one bellow:

```
#!/bin/sh
MIN=60
SEC=$((MIN*60))
ps -eo etimes=,pid= | while read sec pid; do
 if [ ${sec} -gt ${SEC} ]; then
   echo ${pid}
   #kill -9 ${pid} # remove the # at the beginning of the line to actually kill those processes
 fi
done
```

This will display the PIDs of the running processes, one per line

Assuming you name this script **60min.sh**, you can run it every 60 minute using a cron job:

```
0 * * * * /bin/bash /path_to/60min.sh
```

This cron job will run your **60min.sh** script every 60 minutes (or every hour)

Please keep in mind that you might accidentally kill system processes and your system might become unstable or unusable so you will have to reboot.

If you run different processes using a specific linux user I would recommend you to search the processes beloging to that user only and not to user root.